# Transfer data between Windows app form c# and mvc web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr, real-time-updates

I have web page that scan images from scanner in client's device I use SignalR Hub to communicate between web and win app that installed on client's device.
I did code and everything is ok .

Like

- https://www.dynamsoft.com/
- https://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/direct-to-server-php-asp.net-overview.html

But the question is : The scanned images sent to browser was working if i opened connection Name = Client's Device Nmae,
i get it by windows app on client , how to send device name to the same client browser to exchange data between them after (web and windows app call same connetion name (device name)).

Note :
Every User can scan its images from his device.

How client's browser knows the device name on client after installing app on his desltop device.